# How can i run tor through chrome on linux?

Tags: google-chrome, internet, tor

I need to use Tor with Chrome but all the tutorials are for windows, the only one for Ubuntu involve having the vidalia manager but the tor bundles i download dind't come with it.Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: refer [here](http://justplainobvious.blogspot.in/2011/03/how-to-configure-google-chrome-for-tor.html)

Comment: There is a whole Q&A site specific for Tor: http://tor.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not impossible to configure chrome to use Tor. You can do this by, for eg:

```
google-chrome --proxy-server="127.0.0.1:8118;https=127.0.0.1:8118;socks=127.0.0.1:8118;sock4=127.0.0.1:8118;sock5=127.0.0.1:8118,ftp=127.0.0.1:8118" --incognito check.torproject.org
```

or by other methods as described [here](http://justplainobvious.blogspot.in/2011/03/how-to-configure-google-chrome-for-tor.html).

Note that this is **highly discouraged**, because using any browser besides Tor Browser with Tor is not going to give you the protection you needed. The Tor Project [advises](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#TBBOtherBrowser) against this because their [discussions](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/google-chrome-incognito-mode-tor-and-fingerprinting) with Chrome team to add missing APIs, mainly - [Web Request](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/notifications-of-web-request-and-navigation), [Content Scripts](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/content_scripts.html), and the [Proxy APIs](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/proxy%20proposal) - that would be useful for privacy enhancing extensions, were unsuccessful. There are also [several bugs](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/ImportantGoogleChromeBugs) that should be dealt with before even a low-grade privacy-by-design can be provided through Tor in Chrome's Incognito mode.

So, in short,as said in the [FAQ](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#TBBOtherBrowser) :

> Currently, it is impossible to use other browsers and get the same
>   level of protections as when using the Tor Browser.

Comment: not working :((